# I didn't choose X, X chose me

Tags: idioms

Assuming *X* is a non-sentient object or concept, I understand sentiments like "X spoke to me" - it's just a fancy way to say "I liked X immediately." But I don't understand "I didn't choose X, X chose me." Does it simply mean "I liked X," or is there something more to it?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a question here. You just don't like this particular figure of speech.

Comment: This is a humorous or satirical expression as far as I know.

Comment: In it's most pretentious form, this can be an an allusion to the ancient Greek belief in _Muses,_  divine embodiments of certain arts - poetry, history, song, dance, mathematics etc.  As sentient goddesses, they could literally choose a human to act through, so the great writer is actually just a conduit for the muse of writing. The "X chose me." affectation _may_ have descended from a time when high-brow artists would use Greek mythology as a basis for many of their similes, metaphors and other colorful accents to their arts.

Comment: Here are some pictures of the muses: https://www.google.com/search?q=muses+painting&biw=936&bih=832&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv87nJ64bMAhVV7WMKHYSgAnwQsAQIGw&dpr=1

Comment: @Adam - Just my opinion, but I wonder if that should an answer instead of a comment. (Seems pretty deep for a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Could mean that X came naturally or with ease.

> I didn't choose **wakeboarding**, wakeboarding chose me.

Or as pointed out by tojo it could also mean the person had no control over X and was basically forced into X.

> I didn't choose **the thug life**, the thug life chose me.

Comment: I would say that it implies that the speaker felt so compelled to do whatever it was that it was not even an active choice on his/her part. He/she **had no choice** but to do such. It does not necessarily imply it is easy or natural.

Comment: I thought that while I was writing the answer to be fair, I'll add to my answer if that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming X is a non-sentient object or concept

In "X chose me," X is being anthropomorphized into (treated as) not only being capable of thought and choice, but also having more agency over a situation than the speaker does.

This speech move elevates the status of X and contrasts that with the speaker's own (lower) status/agency over the choosing.

I hear this phrase most often to refer to a pet, especially one adopted from a shelter, where it's not as much of a stretch to represent X as being capable of thought and choice.